# How to add new data attribute with javaScript ( using skrollr.js)

Tags: javascript, scroll, custom-data-attribute

In the HTML I have a picture

```
<img id="d1" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png" >
```

I would like to add to it an attribute:

```
data--1000-top="opacity: 0; transform: scale(0.5); bottom: 71px;"
```

It has to actually be written in the code in order for the skrollr.js be able to use it

I added a button that apply this function

```
function myFnc(){
var s = document.getElementById("d1");
s.setAttribute("data-top","transform: scale(1);");
s.setAttribute("data--800-top","transform: scale(0.5);");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Via setAttribute() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute

Little example

```
 var el = document.getElementById("id");
 el.setAttribute("attribute-name","attribute-value");
```

Here a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9E2t2/2/

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer.
I'm trying to use skrollr.js and i tried what you said but it wouldn't work.

Comment: I've added a simple fiddle. If you want better answers you need to give us more details, such as a sample of your code.

Comment: I put your code in a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9E2t2/5/ and works. Maybe the problem is with skrollr init

Comment: Read here https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/issues/35 Try to use this refresh() method each time you change a data attribute. I don't have any other solution by now